# I can't use Theme.AppCompat.Light

Tags: android, styles

I can't use Theme.AppCompat.Light.

I've installed android-support-v7-appcompat.jar but I've done it by following  "Adding libraries without resources" instead of "Adding libraries with resources" as recommended by the training guide of Google.

Is there a problem in that choice?

Thanks for the help...

Comment: you need to reference the library project AppCompat as recommended in the guide. You can refer this after referencing http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a problem in that choice?

Yes. The AppCompat action bar backport will not work that way. Please undo what you did, then attach it as an Android library project to your app. Among other things, this will allow you to reference AppCompat resources, like `Theme.AppCompat.Light`.

Comment: Please share how one should go about doing this